How to publish pact to Pactflow .NET Core PactNet v4.5
I'm writing Pac testing POC for my project. I wrote consumer test, got pact file and try to publish it to PactFlow (we have Pactflow Enterprise - Cloud subscription). The problem is in PactFlow docs here  https://docs.pactflow.io/ I see code example:
//Pact Publisher options
var pactPublisher = new PactPublisher("http://<YOUR_BROKER>.pactflow.io", new PactUriOptions("<TOKEN>")); pactPublisher.PublishToBroker("/pact/to/pacts/dir", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GIT_COMMIT"));
But there is no PactPublisher class in PactNet, I looked at source code https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net and in master and in release 4.x branches I don't see PactPublisher class
Is it possible to publish pact to PactFlow from .NET project? If yes, can anybody share publishing code, please. (another approach like CLI or github actions I didn't try yet, I'm on POC stage, I just want to make it work with one simple test for now).
Thanks in advance
I tried code from official documentation. Expected - code works, actual - it can't work, there is no such class in library

The PactPublisher class is deprecated now github link for pact doc
There are multiple ways to publish pact contract to pact flow now. Some of the common one are:

Pact broker cli (docker image and standalone version)
RESP APIs

I have tried to establish pact publish and verification process using their APIs and library. Below is an article for it with explanation and sample code repository as well.
https://medium.com/@ajaykumar1807/intro-to-pact-for-net-core-integration-with-pactflow-3e159388874c

Thanks! I tried your code, pact is published, very good. Pactflow should use your article instead of outdated not working examples )))

Glad to hear that it helped @SerhiiBond
